# Simple formula for the dimension of weight spaces of Verma module?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, verma-modules

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra (e.g. $\mathfrak{sl}_n$), and let $M_\lambda$ be the Verma module with highest weight $\lambda$. 
**Is there a simple formula for $\dim (M_\lambda)_\mu$, where $(M_\lambda)_\mu$ denotes the weight space with weight $\mu$?** Of course Weyl character formula gives me the generating function, but I am looking for a closed form formula for $\dim (M_\lambda)_\mu$.

---

Edit : Apparently this is called the [Kostant partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kostant_partition_function).

Comment: Which formulation of Weyl's character formula do you mean? I recall it usually being given directly, rather than via a generating function.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft For instance, if you expand $1/\Delta(z)$ into a power series where $\Delta(z)$ is a Weyl denominator, the coefficients of this series are the certain dimensions that I want.

Comment: As you write in your edit, it's the Kostant partition function: the number of ways to write $\lambda-\mu$ as a non-negative integer linear combination of positive roots. You won't get a better formula than that in general.

Comment: @Stephen But isn't Kostant partition function piecewise polynomial? If an explicit form of the piecewise polynomial is known for, say, $A_n$, then that would be helpful.